# What scanf("%d", array + i); does

Tags: c, scanf, pointer-arithmetic

```
void get_elemnts(int *array, int max_index){
    for(int i = 0; i < max_index; i++){
        printf("enter element 0%d: ", i);
        scanf("%d", array + i);
    }
}
```

**scanf("%d", array + i);**Can someone explain? I have a code that gets the elements of an array from the user input. And at the moment I have difficulties with understanding what exactly this part of the code does

Comment: It iterates along `array` obtaining an input for each element. `array + i` is the same as `&array[i]`.

Comment: For any pointer or array `array` and index `i`, the expression `array[i]` is exactly equal to `*(array + i)`. From that follows that `&array[i]` will be equal to `array + i`.

Comment: There must be a decent duplicate for this - but I can't find it with a quick search.

Comment: I think reading this question will help you a lot (https://stackoverflow.com/a/381549/12330258)

Comment: @AdrianMole, if you can't find it no one can :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function definition

```
void get_elemnts(int *array, int max_index){
    for(int i = 0; i < max_index; i++){
        printf("enter element 0%d: ", i);
        scanf("%d", array + i);
    }
}
```

is equivalent to

```
void get_elemnts(int *array, int max_index){
    for(int i = 0; i < max_index; i++){
        printf("enter element 0%d: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &array[i] );
    }
}
```

This expression `array + i` gives pointer to the i-th element of the array.

The format `%d` used in the function `scanf` expects a pointer to an object of the type `int` and this expression `array + i` yields the pointer using the pointer arithmetic.

The expression `array[i]`  is equivalent to the expression   `*( array + i )`.

So the expression `&array[i]` is the same as `&*( array + i )` where the applied operators `&*` can be omitted and you will get just `( array + i )`.

Answer (score 3):

There are three concepts involved:

1. `scanf("%d", pointer)` method will read the integer value (`%d`) from `stdin` and write it to the memory referenced by `pointer`.
2. Nature of arrays: arrays in C are stored linearly in memory: int array of size `n` is just `n * sizeof(int)` bytes in memory and the variable of the array is the same as the pointer to its first element.
3. Pointer arithmetic: `array + i` moves the pointer by `i` memory cells of type int which is `i * sizeof(int)` bytes. This is exactly where the i'th element of array is. So `array + i` is a pointer to `array[i]`.